# Excel VBA Combobox search for worksheet and display data table in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 100+ worksheet, In a Userform, I have a `combobox` that search worksheets and 5 `textboxes` that send data to any selected worksheet from the `combobox`. Now I want to add a `LISTBOX` that when I select worksheet in the `combobox`, `LISTBOX` will display the data (Multiple `column` and `Row`) of the selected worksheet everytime I click the worksheet name in the `combobox`. I have a code but only `active sheet` is shown in the `listbox` when I open worksheet tabs.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

 With Me.ListBox1
    .RowSource = ""
    .ColumnCount = 7
    .ColumnWidths = "80;180;80;80;1;20"
    ListBox1.RowSource = Sheets("910-001").Range("C7:I1000").Address
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    With Me.ListBox1
        .RowSource = ""
        .ColumnCount = 7
        .ColumnWidths = "80;180;80;80;1;20"
        .RowSource = Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("C7:I1000").Address
    End With

End Sub
```

It looks like the problem is that you are using a literal value as an index for the Sheets collection. This guarantees that one sheet will always be used: "910-001".

My suggestion with this answer is that you replace the literal value with a reference to the current value of ComboBox1. Then, the user-selected worksheet data will be used as the list in ListBox1.

Notice also, that I chose to use the Worksheets collection as opposed to the Sheets collection. This is being more specific (which is generally a good thing), as the Sheets collection includes chart sheets, while the Worksheets collection is comprised of only worksheets. This makes the call slightly more efficient, but more importantly guarantees that a worksheet is returned from the collection.

Comment: A sentence or two (or even a short paragraph) by way of explanation would have gone a long way toward making this a great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dennis.

Comment: Is `ListBox1.RowSource` necessary? Seems it could be just `.RowSource` as it is within the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).